# Why I cannot use as entry point in C# app a generic type?

Tags: c#, generics, entry-point

In C# the method Main must be in a nongeneric type in order to be selected as entry point. Why is that?

I'm a little bit confused about that because that is possible in Java (the function main() can be in a generic class).

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program<T> //incorrect
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What's the logic? You cannot expect it to know what `T` should be, nor to "default" it to `object` or whatever.

Comment: What type do you imagine the operating system will choose to get the program started?

Comment: How should `T` be chosen when creating the class? It works in java because generic types are erased at runtime.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes, I believe so. But it doesn't really matter. Something has to call it, and that something needs to know `T`, and it doesn't.

Comment: As far as I understand a quick check on Java static methods in generic classes, is that Java doesn't actually create different methods implementations per type, but rather a static method is the same for the general type. The static type can't be used either in static methods in Java .Net (C#) does create specific static methods for the generic type. The Type can also be used inside the methods (static variables also have their own value per type). This does mean however that to use a static method, C# must know its type (which the program doesn't), where java doesn't need to know.

Comment: Where did you read that everything that is possible in java should be possible in C#? I cannot find that reference.

Answer (score 1):

The `Main` method serves as a fixed interface to the operating system, which itself has no mechanism to select and specify a type to be given as a parameter.