# Generic list and static main

Tags: c#-4.0, generic-list

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace ConsoleApplication74
{
class Program<T>
{
    public void Add(T X)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", X);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        Program<string> MyGeneric = new Program<string>();
        MyGeneric.Add("ABC");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

I have erroe `Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point`.
Program.cs properties has Build Action as Compile.
I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I cannot use as entry point in C# app a generic type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045923/why-i-cannot-use-as-entry-point-in-c-sharp-app-a-generic-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Main` method, or entry point in your program, cannot be in a class that has generic arguments. Your `Program` class has a `T` type argument. The C# specification calls this out in section 3.1 under Application Startup:

> The application entry point method may not be in a generic class declaration.

You should make a new class instead of trying to use `Program`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        MyClass<string> MyGeneric = new MyClass<string>();
        MyGeneric.Add("ABC");
        Console.Read();
    }
}

class MyClass<T>
{
    public void Add(T X)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", X);
    }   
}
```

Comment: So how can I use my own generic type??

Comment: Thank you very much. When I saw your first answer I just had this solution in my head. Thanks!